# How to edit a previously asked Stack Exchange question?

Tags: support, edits

How to edit a previously asked question on this site?

Whenever I click the question, the page gets refreshed and I get redirected to the question again.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Click the 'edit' link.]

Click the edit link that is highlighted above.

Comment: You seem to have a browser extension that puts links under random keywords. Is it an adware or did you install that on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Just below the question you will see a set of "tags" - and just below that, (when you are logged in), you will see a few gray links that look like this:

share | edit | close | delete | flag

The edit link should do the trick.

Good luck.

Comment: So, now that you know how to edit a question, - do you know how to up-vote helpful answers (and comments) --- and how to mark clear and concise answers as correct?